# Problem with 'unused arguments' in auc function

Tags: r, arguments, auc

I'm trying to compute area under curve value by using auc function from pROC package.
However facing still the same error about 'unused arguments'.

```
sub_2 <- c("No","No","No","No","Yes","Yes","No","No","No","No")
pred_yes <- c(0.36,0.12,0.6,0.6,0.28,0.4,0.08,0.04,0.48,0.00)

auc(actual=ifelse(sub_2 == "Yes",1,0),predicted = pred_yes)
```

The error as below shows up:

```
Error in auc(actual = ifelse(sub_2 == "Yes", 1, 0), predicted = pred_yes): unused arguments (actual = ifelse(sub_2 == "Yes", 1, 0), predicted = pred_yes)
Traceback:
```

It shows on kaggle kernel and localy on my mac.No idea what is the problem in here. Could You please help me with that ?

Comment: What does `?auc` tell you?    Are there  options called "actual" and "predicted"?

Comment: Yes, they are. I know that I need to specify both values. First thought was that I have wrong data types, so I changed 'actual' and 'predicted' to matrix type and problem still exists.

Comment: The documentation says no, but there are  "predictor" and "response".

Answer (score 0):

The auc function with arguments "actual" and "predicted" is in Metrics package.
You can also resolve the error by calling the right package.